# how to get CKAN full search results

Tags: ckan

I'd like to plot search results on the map. For that, I need the full results list instead of the paginated results. Currently I use c.page.items to fetch the items, but that gives me only the items on the current page.

How can I get the full search results? Only by looping through the pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API function [package_search](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search) to get up to 1000 datasets. If that is not enough, maybe it is an option to talk to SOLR directly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is it possible to do it with only 1 search query? since the results are returned, but just paginated it is redundant and can create inconsistencies between 2 search queries.

Comment: There is a hard limit int he API. The potential inconsistencies between requests when paging is a challenge. If you have a solution for server-side, do suggest it as a CKAN issue. Or if you need to cope client-side then here's an example: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/pull/158/files#diff-a534488ef7ff47de140c638341f46001R78